# Add /public in local enviroment laravel

Tags: laravel-4

In my local server launched with artisan serve need to specify the path to save the files to / public + path to the directory to save. In my real server as points directly to public is not necessary. Anyone know how to fix this to not having to change routes every time I'm in the local environment?

Answer (score 1):

I always use URL::to('asset path') for links, and base_path() for server folders, and it seems to work for me.

An example I just dug up from my own app:
$file->move(base_path()."/public/uploads/".$type.'/', $filename);

Comment: There's a whole bunch of helpers as well for URL generation: http://laravel.com/docs/helpers#urls